# AWS Lambda Python + RDS - Token not accepted as password

Tags: python, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, pymysql

I'm facing a problem with authenticating to RDS from Python 3.9 Lambda using IAM Roles with either mysql-connector-python 8.0.27 or PyMySQL 1.0.2 modules. In both cases the problem is that token is not passed inside connection string

In case of mysql.connect I'm using this construct:

```
os.environ['LIBMYSQL_ENABLE_CLEARTEXT_PLUGIN'] = '1'

token = client.generate_db_auth_token(DBHostname=hostname, Port=port, DBUsername=username)

mysql.connector.connect(host=hostname, user=username, passwd=token, database=dbname, auth_plugin='mysql_clear_password')
```

but getting `ubyte format requires 0 <= number <= 255` error which leads me to believe that token string is too long and lib can't support it

So I tried switching to PyMySQL, but now it fails with  `"Access denied for user 'mydbuser'@'172.16.1.246' (using password: NO)")`

```
os.environ['LIBMYSQL_ENABLE_CLEARTEXT_PLUGIN'] = '1'
....
token = client.generate_db_auth_token(DBHostname=hostname, Port=port, DBUsername=username)

my_db = pymysql.connect(
    host=hostname,
    user=username,
    password=token,
    database=dbname,
    connect_timeout=2)
```

Token is generated and I see it in logs, IAM roles/policies are correct as I'm able to connect from Lambda using standard password, or using mysql CLI client on EC2 with token (MySQL community client, not MariaDB because it doesn't support `--enable-cleartext-plugin` option)

I even hardcoded the token, and still it fails with "no password"

**UPDATE #1:**

After more experiments I took a token that was generated from AWS CLI `aws rds generate-db-auth-token --hostname my-mysql-db.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com --port 3306 --region us-east-2 --username mydbuser`  put it in mysql-connector-python's code and it magically worked!

I've compared two tokens and the difference is that `aws rds generate-db-auth-token` returns header called `X-Amz-Signature` 64 bytes long, so mysql-connector processes it fine.

However,  boto3 `client.generate_db_auth_token` returns header called `X-Amz-Security-Token` 820 bytes long and it utterly destroys poor mysql-connector

A bug? A feature? Is it possible to get 64-bit header?

PyMySQL didn't work with either of tokens, so probably a bug in that library itself

**UPDATE #2:**

I've decided to test the tokens themselves on mysql client and got quite confusing results:

- When using token made from Long-term AWS access key (the one which starts with 'AKIA') and generated via `aws rds generate-db-auth-token` I was able to connect to DB
- When using token from lambda's `client.generate_db_auth_token` - that token didn't work in mysql CLI either - getting `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'lambdauser'@'172.16.1.20' (using password: YES)` - The main difference is that Lambda is using Short-term access key (starts with 'ASIA')

Could it be that lambda's access key is somehow out of sync? Or Lambda needs extra roles/policies to make tokens trusted by other AWS services?

MySQL command format:

`mysql --host=$RDSHOST --port=3306  --enable-cleartext-plugin --user=lambdauser --password=$TOKEN`

Comment: I am facing the exact same issue with the python 3.9 boto3 in AWS Lambda where the X-Amz-Security-Token received is too large for the mysql connector.

The 
*Error:-*
While connecting failed due to :ubyte format requires 0 <= number <= 255

Comment: Works in the bash cli with below command though,
mysql -h cluster.cluster-bkxjsgug.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com -P 3306 --enable-cleartext-plugin --user=dbaservice --password=$(aws rds generate-db-auth-token --hostname cluster.cluster-bkxjsgug.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com --port 3306 --region us-west-2 --username dbaservice)
Not sure if its mysql library not being able to handle the large set of string response received.